# Column formatting issue in SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, lookup-column, modern-experience, column-formatting

I am in need of help on an important topic.

So, I have a SharePoint list that uses column formatting for one of the columns to auto-generate it based on some other fields present in the list (these other fields are a single line of texts, lookup columns linked with another list on the same site)

The problem is that when the list is viewed in the default view, the Title field gets auto-populated and everything works as it should, but when I double click to open an item, that's when the Title field gives up. It displays [object object] instead of what it should be showing. eg. if the Title that was generated is "ABC Hello There HT 101", it displays it as "ABC [object object] object object"

I've tried to fix this for so long but have come up empty-handed.

Any reason as to why this is happening?

Any help is appreciated. Is the column formatting only supposed to work for the base level? or is there a different issue altogether?

Comment: Check this thread https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/problem-formatting-json-with-search-choice-column/m-p/2191242 to see if it will help you.

Comment: Can you add the JSON you used in your question? How you have added/concatenated lookup value in JSON? Also, JSON formatting only **displays** the value --> it does not **save/store** value in list columns.